# pass array to go-pg query

Tags: go, go-pg

I'm using Go-pg and when I use the following way to execute sql query:

```
db.Query(&result, sqlQuery, params)
```

where `params` is a structure like the following:

```
type MyParams struct {
    Codes []int
}
```

and `sqlQuery` is

```
SELECT id FROM bar WHERE code_id IN (?codes)
```

in the actual SQL query I get query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM bar WHERE code_id IN ('[7,45]')
```

Is it possible to have int array placeholder passed properly to have a query:

```
SELECT id FROM bar WHERE code_id IN (7,45)
```

Comment: loop through array and convert to string with delimiter `,`

Comment: @Himanshu this way if i got u correctly I'll get `id IN ('7,45')` which is not what I need

Comment: Use [pg.Array](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg#Array)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do:

1. Keep using `in (...)` and use [`pg.In`](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg#In).
2. Use [`= any(array)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) in your SQL instead of `in (list)` and [`pg.Array`](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg#Array) in Go to send a proper array to PostgreSQL.

The first looks like:

```
db.Query(&result, `SELECT id FROM bar WHERE code_id IN (?)`, pg.In(params.Codes))
```

the second looks like:

```
db.Query(&result, `SELECT id FROM bar WHERE code_id = ANY (?)`, pg.Array(params.Codes))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the go-pg ORM instead for the same results:

```
ids := []int{1, 2, 3}
err := db.Model((*Book)(nil)).
    Where("id in (?)", pg.In(ids)).
    Select()

// SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

A way is to create a string with delimiter required to make an string and then pass it to the `db.query` to fetch the result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    a := []int{7,45,32}
    str := ConvertToString(a, ",")
    query := `Select * from table1 where ID IN(`+ str +`)`
    fmt.Println(query)
}

func ConvertToString(a []int, delim string) string{
    var b string
    for _, v := range a{
        b += strconv.Itoa(v)
        b += ","
    }
    return strings.Trim(b,",")
}
```

Working code on [Playground](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#inQueries).

**Edited**:-

You can use [Golang sqlx](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#inQueries) package for your requirement.

> `database/sql` package does not inspect your query and it passes your
>   arguments directly to the driver, it makes dealing with queries with
>   IN clauses difficult:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE level IN (?);
```

> When this gets prepared as a statement on the backend, the bindvar ?
>   will only correspond to a single argument, but what is often desired
>   is for that to be a variable number of arguments depending on the
>   length of some slice, eg:

```
var levels = []int{4, 6, 7}
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE level IN (?);", levels)
```

Comment: When I do this I get the following generated query: `SELECT id FROM bar WHERE code_id IN ('7,45')`

Comment: @XZen No you will not when you create a query using that. Please check updated answer with query generated.

Comment: Same function with reduction in memory allocation: https://play.golang.org/p/JuXR-P8prEd

Comment: @Himanshu, got it, but my goal is to use go-pg and it's placeholders feature, so that I could avoid strings manipulations, which is not the safest way to build queries. If there's no way to do it using go-pg it'll be sad and I'll go with the way like one you've just provided, thank you.

Comment: @XZen you can still add string and pass it to sql query you are creating it dynamically

Comment: @XZen Check updated answer for your question. you can bind an array directly.